# TFS Build Unit Test with Oracle Instant Client

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, tfs, build, msbuild

I am running TFS 2013 Update 2 on Windows 2008 R2.
I installed the Oracle Instant client 32 and 64. I've tried it with both clients 32/64 and changed the test run mode from x86 to x64.

--Update - I am using Tnsnames.ora and the user\schema and passwords are embedded in the config files. I don't think this is a user or password issue.

--Update - 2 
I ran another test. If I delete the oracle folder the Build changes the error to:Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater. So the build controller is finding the oracle client. But it's not reading the tns.ora?? It's in the same folder.
I followed these instructions to add the tnsnames.ora as a registry key entry
How can Instant Client on Windows use registry settings?
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE for a global setting
2. Add ORACLE group key. 
3. Add a new string value within the ORACLE key for the different settings you are interested in (NLS_LANG, TNS_ADMIN, etc.)
**I rebooted and it still does does not run in the build.**

I am running some basic CRUD Oracle test to validate the SPs in our applications.
On the build server we have Visual Studio and it will run the Unit test without issues. That tells me the Oracle client is working fine.

When I run the TFS build and the Unit test, I get the below error:

> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not
>   resolve the connect identifier specified

**------Resolved----------**
 I had to change the permissions on the folder to let the service account have admin access.

Comment: Terminology is important: If you're touching a database, it's not a unit test, it's an *integration* test.

Comment: I am using VS Unit Tests in a build. So it matters what I call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username that is running the build doesn't resolve the Oracle database name. Connect on the build agent with that user and try to do a tnsping.

Comment: --Update - I am using Tnsnames.ora and the user\schema and passwords are embedded in the config files. I don't think this is a user or password issue.

Comment: It's not a Oracle username/password issue; it's the problem that the user that is running the TFS build doesn't have access to that tnsnames.ora from the build agent(machine).

Comment: How would that be? The build agent runs under it's on credentials. It does not matter who started the build.  The agent runs on the server and should have access to all the files on the server. I've verified the agent account is admin on the server. The instant client uses the path to find the oracle dlls and the tns.ora. -- To test your idea.  I removed the tns.ora file and the error is the same.  So if the build controller can't see the oracle files. What do I do to make it find them?  -- Also my build agent is on the TFS server.

Comment: I ran another test. If I delete the oracle folder the Build changes the error to:Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.  So the build controller is finding the oracle client. But it's not reading the tns.ora?? It's in the same folder.

Comment: Use the build agent's credentials to remotely connect to the TFS server then test the Oracle client.

Comment: Yes, I have connected to the build server as service account and the Unit Tests run fine inside visual Studio.

Comment: Hi, ds19. I am going to mark this as the accepted answer.  You were right about it not having access.  It's very odd because it was using the dlls in that folder for oracle. but not reading the tnsnames.ora. I had to change the permissions on the folder to let the service account have admin access.